# How to figure out whether the series is convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{p(p+1)(p+2)...(p+n-1)}{n!}\times\frac{1}{n^q}}$$p and q are constants. I tried d'Alembert's ratio test, and here is the result:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{p(p+1)(p+2)...(p+n-1)(p+n)}{(n+1)!}\times\frac{1}{(n+1)^q}}{\frac{p(p+1)(p+2)...(p+n-1)}{n!}\times\frac{1}{n^q}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{(p+n)n^q}{(n+1)^{q+1}}}$$What is the next step could be?

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test is almost always too weak, your limit is $1,$ naturally. A better way is Gauss's test (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html): $$\frac{(p+n)n^q}{(n+1)^{q+1}}=1-\frac{q-p+1}{n}+O(n^{-2}),$$ the series is convergent for $q-p+1>1,$ i.e. $p<q,$ and divergent otherwise.

Comment: Ought to be upvoted and accepted.